# Power View in SharePoint 2013 is not refreshing

Tags: excel, sharepoint-2013, oledbconnection

When we use OLEDB hive drive in SharePoint the Power View is not refreshing.

It shows the following error:

> An error occurred while working on the Data Model in the workbook. Please try again.
>
> We were unable to refresh one or more data connections in this workbook.
> The following connections failed to refresh:

Comment: There are to little details given 
- what's the farm configuration (one server, multiple ones - can be SSO issue)
- what's the connection configuration for work book? Secure Store, Pass Through or stored in work book? 
- Unattended account is configured for power pivot? 
- Is SharePoint using Claims authentication, Classic Windows or other?